# Automatically start JetBrains softwares as root (via plank shortcuts) on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: permissions, root

I'm very new to Linux environment, I came from Windows.

I've installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my machine (an XPS 15 9550 with a dual boot - Win10), a plank and a theme (macbuntu, don't blame me :p).

I'm used to code with WebStorm & PhpStorm, so I've installed both of them and I've created a shortcut using **Tools -> Create Desktop Entry...** via the soft.

Now my shortcuts are inside the plank and I would like to start those applications as root automatically.

I've tried to edit **/usr/share/applications/jetbrains-xxxx.desktop** to modify `Exec` command to :

`Exec: gksudo -k -u root <DEFAULT_COMMAND>`

But it doesn't seems to work. The software never asks me a password and I can't edit my files because of permission denied on the folder I am working on (I think).

I want to edit files inside **/var/www/html/*** (fresh LAMP installation). Those folders belong to `root:plugdev`. I've tried to change this to `www-data:www-data` and to add my user to this group but it fails. My user also belongs to `plugdev`.

I don't know what I should do :

- try to change the UGO rights to 775 (current is 755)
- continue to search a way to start my softs as root. I like this idea because I can do this just once and it's good forever.

Thanks for your help :).

Comment: These software applications are not designed to be run as root , they can handle the privilege changes themselves. If you insist on running them as root ensure you are fully patched up to date and aware of https://blog.jetbrains.com/blog/2016/05/11/security-update-for-intellij-based-ides-v2016-1-and-older-versions/

Comment: Have you logged out and in again since making the group changes

Comment: Thanks for your answer. No I haven't. I'll try this. So I sould use `www-data` ? Or is it better to keep `root:plugdev` with 775 instead of 755 ? (I don't know if changing the default user:group matters to LAMP)

Comment: its better not to change the permissions of a webroot, there are security implications

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jetbrains IDE's have a deployment module that will handle the permissions changes for you so you don't have to weaken security, there is a specific option for "in-place server" that handles your scenario.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.1/deployment.html